# Create a copy of video (.mp4) file android

Tags: android

I would like to copy an existing video file to another video file.

I trying to do it like this:

```
    byte c;
    try {
        FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream (VIDEO_PATH_TMP);
        FileInputStream oldFile = new FileInputStream (VIDEO_PATH);
        while ((c = (byte) oldFile.read()) != -1) {
            newFile.write(c);
        }

        newFile.close();
        oldFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it doesn't work. The output file was created, but i can't see the video.

How can i implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the answer and this is the code:

```
 try {

        FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream (VIDEO_PATH_TMP);
        FileInputStream oldFile = new FileInputStream (VIDEO_PATH);

         // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = oldFile.read(buf)) > 0) {
            newFile.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        newFile.close();
        oldFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I just added the Buffer array and it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call flush before close:

```
newFile.flush();
newFile.close();
```